# Can DPM 2010 backup Exchange 2007 LCR enabled storage groups?

Tags: backup, exchange-2007, scdpm

My organization is currently evaluating DPM 2010 RC for backing up Exchange 2007 storage groups. When selecting group members from the "Create New Protection Group" dialog, the only storage groups that render selectable are those that do not have LCR enabled. Does DPM 2010 support backing up Exchange 2007 LCR enabled storage groups?

Here's our environment:

- Single Exchange Server
- LCR enabled for all exchange databases
- Windows Server 2008 SP2
- Exchange 2007 SP2, Rollup 2
- All databases hosted from a SAN array

Answer (score 1):

DPM 2010 absolutely does support Exchange 2007 LCR storage groups. Here are a couple leads to get you started troubleshooting:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb795725.aspx (written for DPM 2007 but the issues are exactly the same in 2010)

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2008/08/25/449684.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question over email on the technet DPM blog and received the following response. We tried the registry setting change and found it worked. Thank you DPM!

http://blogs.technet.com/dpm/

To display the Exchange LCR-enabled storage groups in the DPM New Protection Group Wizard, use the following set key command to disable the (LCR) VSS replica writer.
set key EnableVssWriter under
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\Replay\Parameters to 0 DWORD type

Note: After setting the registry key, you must restart the Microsoft Exchange Replication Service.
For more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb795725.aspx